# Update PostgreSQL foreign data wrappers automatically on server connection in DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, foreign-data-wrapper

I have set up foreign data wrappers (FDW) between two PostgreSQL dev servers in DBeaver. This enables me to execute queries that call tables in both servers, which is very useful.

However, table information is not updated for tables accessed through a FDW, which means that queries sometimes fail due to changes in a table (column name change, for instance). Since this is a development environment, this type of change is to be expected. The only way of updating a <s>FDW</s> *foreing table*, in my experience, is to drop and recreate it.

Is it possible to run a <s>FDW</s> *foreign table* creation script automatically on server connection? Dropping and recreating all <s>FDWs</s> *foreign tables* upon connection would update informations on all foreign tables and make sure that queries always use updated information.

I have tried using the Shell Command window [in the Connection Properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raM1s.png) to call my FDW creation script but this does not seem to have any effect apart from [displaying an empty `psql` pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrZ3I.png) on startup. FDWs are not updated.

**Version info**
DBeaver 21.2.1
PostgreSQL 12.2

Comment: You have to drop and recreate the foreign tables. And that should be done every time something changes on the foreign server. Just recreating a foreign table when connecting to your database, won't change a lot: Connections can stay open for hours/days/weeks and the foreign server can change something any second. You will always be the last one to find out.

Comment: In this particular use case, the connection is reopened at least once per day. This would be an acceptable update frequency.

Comment: Write a SQL script, and schedule a cron job that executes this script using psql.

Comment: Hadn't thought of this workaround, sounds like an acceptable temporary solution. However, it's strange that the Shell Command option does not work as I intuitively thought it would.